# Which is correct - "all the people are students" or "all the people are a student" or "all the people are student"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which one is correct:

a. All the people are students here.
b. All the people are a student here.
c. All the people are student here.

Some one told me "a" and "b" are correct.
I believed just "a" is correct. While searching more about it, I came across bare nouns. Now I guess "a" and "c" are possible answers. So would you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**All** is usually used with plural verb forms, especially when we say "all the X" or "all of the X" where *X* is plural.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv266.shtml)  "The people" is plural, because there are more than one, so "all of the people" is likewise plural, and the correct answer is A,

> All of the people are students.

B is not correct because "a student" is singular, but "all of the people" is plural.  "All of the people are a student" - what, all of them are one single student?  That doesn't make sense.

C is incorrect because *student* is a count noun and needs either an article or to be plural: you can "be a student" or you can "be students", but you can't just "be student".

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "people" is plural, so you must use "students" to describe them. So only A. is correct.

In some contexts, "people" can be singular, referring to one group of people. However, that can't be possible in this sentence since "a student" can only refer to one individual, not a group.